# Turn on Android display when someone approaches the device

Tags: android, computer-vision

Using a bit of computer vision, I'd like to turn on the display of a wall-mounted Android device when a human walks up to (w/in 2 feet of) the device.

I'm an experienced developer, but I know next to nothing about computer vision. Programmatically turning on the display is easy enough. Any guidance, reading suggestions, tutorials, places to start, etc. would be appreciated.

Edit: To clarify after some comments in the answers -- since this is a permanently-ish wall mount situation, the device will have full-time power. Battery life is a non-issue.

Answer (score 3):

Android has Proximity and Light Sensors, but I don't think those are good enough for your need.

If the display has a front camera, you could probable use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) along with some form of [Motion detection](http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/blog/detecting-webcam-movement-with-opencv/) to detect when someone approaches close to the screen.

EDIT: Here are the docs for Computer Vision using OpenCV.. http://docs.opencv.org/

Answer (score 3):

I think there are three ways of doing this.

1. Use the camera and face recognition
2. Use the proximity sensor
3. Use the microphone for detecting noise
4. (Use the magnetic sensor and force the user to carry a strong magnet with him)

The problem with the forst one is: Power consumption
The problem with the second one is: Very inaccurate sensors and a bad API
The problem with the third one is: difficult to recognize the "real" sounds

You can read about the proximity sensor [here](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.de/2011/01/proximity-sensor-on-android-gingerbread.html) and of course [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html).

Comment: if the display is going to be wall mounted, I assumed it would be plugged into a power source and and I gave my answer regd. that. But your fourth answer is the best! :D

Comment: What are your feelings on light sensor vs. camera detection?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure, but I would say you can use the light sensor since the light value changes when someone walks close.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  if( event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
    //do something
  }
}
```